# Post Data format is diffrent then what I needed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json, http

I am having a simple problem while making a request to server for updating a name field. I need to post some data in this format:-

```
   {"api_token"=>"api", "device_token"=>"device", "user"=>{"name"=>"mohit"}, "id"=>"4"}
```

But when i am trying to post something its posting in this format:-

```
  {"user"=>"(\n        {\n        name = ChangeName;\n    }\n)", "api_token"=>"api", "device_token"=>"device", "id"=>"4"}
```

I am not able to figure out how to change my code to generate proper request. Here is the code that I am using.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/users/4?api_token=api&device_token=device"]];
NSMutableDictionary *dict= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Mike",@"name", nil];
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict, nil];
        [request setPostValue:array forKey:@"user"];
         [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

Please let me know if i need to post some more code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIFormDatRequest setPostValue:forKey: wants strings, not structures.  It ends up calling description to convert them to strings and you're getting the printable description of an array with a dictionary in it.

Rails uses a naming scheme that allows you to simulate a hierarchy in a flat space using a field naming convention detailed at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html.  You should read that and understand the html produced by the form helpers.

Try:

```
[request setPostValue:@"mohit" forKey:@"user[name]"];
```

and rails will unpack it into the proper kind of collection on the server.

Comment: Yeah Exactly, I am getting printable form of the an array with a dictionary in it. I tried to directly hit from the terminal and as I see console the server was reading it as "user"=>{"name"=>"mohit"} but when I tried to send the same using ASIHttpRequest it was showing  {"user"=>"(\n        {\n        name = ChangeName;\n    }\n)". Now you can undersand I just need a way to convert {"user"=>"(\n        {\n        name = ChangeName;\n    }\n)"  into "user"=>{"name"=>"mohit"}. Any help?

Comment: For my app, "user"=>{"name"=>"mohit"} <----- this form gives correct response success.

Comment: I do not understand what your server actually wants.  HTTP allows only flat lists of key value pairs, not hierarchies.  ASIFormDataRequest will take a dictionary { "foo"=>"fa"; "bar"="ba" } and turn it into the HTTP query string ?foo=fa&bar=ba.  The only way to get hierarchy into query strings is to fake it by sending JSON as a value

Comment: ok. But How can I achieve that on iOS sdk? Is there no such method in ASIHttpRequest framework that can provide me required encoding? or is there anything that can be done on server side ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to answer the question - what encoding does the server want? Is there a static http form you can create that produces the right results?  Post the code for that.

Comment: The application (server side) is developed in Ruby On rails.

Comment: One more thing I can tell that it uses UTF8String encoding on server side.

Comment: Thanks A trillion times. It made it.