# POST from iPhone using SVHTTPRequest to Rails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, post

I'm trying to make a simple POST request to my sample rails app from iPhone using SVHTTPRequest, but I am having trouble flattening out the hash that rails is expecting. Trying to post a 'blog post' just using the title, so it is looking for `params[:post]` and I need to create

```
{:post => {:title => "Sample Title"}
```

But I seem to be creating this instead, which rails really isn't liking (out of the log)

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-21 10:56:26 -0500
  Processing by PostsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"post"=>"{\n    title = \"iphone title\"", "\n}"=>nil}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "{\n    title = \"iphone title\"":String):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

Ignoring the fact that it doesn't like the CSRF token and what not, why is my hash being flattened into that? Here is what generates it

```
NSDictionary *title = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"iphone title" forKey:@"title"];
NSDictionary *to_post = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:title forKey:@"post"];
[SVHTTPRequest POST:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"
         parameters: posting #etc
```

I've gathered from posts like this one [Post Data format is diffrent then what I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246098/post-data-format-is-diffrent-then-what-i-needed) that the auto flattening of NSDictionary is not done correctly , but I'm having trouble translating the solution for ASCIHTTP to this new format of SVHTTP